# Caching suds-object. Unicode problem

Tags: django, memcached, pickle, suds

I'm using suds https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ to fetch data using SOAP. I'd like to cache the result (using memcached) to not overload the server from where I'm fetching the data. The problem is when fetching the cached data. Fetching it works fine but then django tries to decode the data (force_unicode) and it fails with the following:

```
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was:  armv�rmare t
```

This is what I use to cache the result (where result = suds-object). Using cPickle (and tried pickle just in case but without success, no surprise).

The suds response is in unicode.

```
#Cache the result 
cache.set(hashstring, pickle.dumps(result), 120) 
#Return the cached data
result = cache.get(hashstring) 
if result: 
    return pickle.loads(result, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suds responses can't be easily pickled because they are dynamically generated classes. Suds uses the WSDL to generate a 'schema' for the request with which it dynamically creates a class tailored for each method. When you make the request, an instance of this dynamic class is created and populated with the response information. Restoring a pickled class instance obviously requires the class itself and here is where suds' approach causes problems because pickle doesn't know about these dynamic classes.

One approach for you would be to create your own classes to represent the response information. you can populate an instance of this class with the suds response and this class will be easy to pickle!

Once the information is pickle-able, it should be fine to put it into memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive that memcached supports storage of complex objects?

Another thing to consider is that SUDS has its own [caching mechanism](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#PERFORMANCE) built-in, but I believe it is only for the WSDL/XSD data, so that it doesn't have to be recompiled every time you startup.  I am not totally positive, however, and it's possible that it could also be used for storage of results.

Comment: I'm not sure memcached supports it but I've also tried to store to a file with pickle and I get problems there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suds returns a `suds.sax.text.Text` object, which is a subclass of the Python Unicode string object. I think explicitly casting that object to Unicode would solve your problem.

```
#Cache the result 
cache.set(hashstring, unicode(result), 120) 
#Return the cached data
result = cache.get(hashstring) 
if result:
    return result
```